# How to refer to RDF statements in JSON-LD? How to state(ment) about statements?

Tags: rdf, json-ld, hydra-core

Suppose you have a simple RDF statement `x:Object x:predicate x:Subject`, which is expressed in JSON-LD as `{"@id": "x:Object", "x:predicate": {"@id": "x:Subject"}}`. How do you refer to the specific object-predicate-subject relation, how do you "adress" the factual relation? What's the `"@id"` or the inline identity of a statement in JSON-LD? How do you ascribe "meta data" to a statement?

How do you express statements in JSON-LD, where the subject is another statement, e.g. `[x:Subject x:predicate x:Object] x:metaPredicate x:MetaObject`?

How do you express statements in JSON-LD, where the object is another statement, e.g. `x:MetaSubject x:metaPredicate [x:Subject x:predicate x:Object]`?

How do you express statements in JSON-LD, where the predicate is another statement (strange but possible), e.g. `x:MetaSubject [x:Subject x:predicate x:Object] x:MetaObject`?

(PS: I realize the `[]` syntax of my samples is not conformant Turtle, but they serve to express my thoughts/questions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use reification, there exists a [standardized vocabulary](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_reificationvocab) for that. In JSON-LD it would look somewhat like this:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "subject": { "@id": "rdf:subject", "@type": "@id" },
    "predicate": { "@id": "rdf:predicate", "@type": "@id" },
    "object": { "@id": "rdf:object", "@type": "@id" }
  },
  "@type": "rdf:Statement",
  "subject": "x:Subject",
  "predicate": "x:predicate",
  "object": { "@id": "x:Object" },
  "x:metaPredicate": "x:MetaObject"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Markus, I thought about doing it this way, i.e. using RDF means to deconstruct a single statement into a "named" set of multiple statements for each semantic element, which would all reify into the "current truth", so that I can ascribe further statements to that "named" thing. Yes, that'll work. However, it seems very cumbersome and I thought there is a more concise form. If there is none, maybe the JSON-LD expert group could consider it to be a very much wished-for feature to have in future versions of JSON-LD.

Comment: The alternative is to [use named graphs](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#named-graphs) but [from an RDF point of view the semantics are not well-enough defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-datasets/) be generally recommendable.

Answer (score 1):

One may now be able to reference an RDF triple in JSON-LD by using **JSON-LD***, or **JSON-LD-star**.

### Referencing a triple as the subject

JSON-LD* builds on top of RDF*, which is already supported by some tooling, and makes it possible to use an RDF triple in place of the subject, e.g.:

```
<< s pred o >> pred2 o2
```

in this way:

```
{
  "@id": {"@id": "s", "pred": {"@id": "o"}},
  "pred2": {"@id": "o2" }
}
```

### Referencing a triple as the object

It should be noted that the JSON-LD structure for using an RDF triple as an *object* is a bit awkward, and this:

```
s pred << s2 pred2 o >>
```

requires a `@reverse`, expressed like this:

```
{
  "@id": {
    "@id": "s2",
    "pred2": {"@id": "o"}
  },
  "@reverse": {
    "pred": {"@id": "s"}
  }
}
```

### See also

- [W3C community group JSON-LD-star spec draft](https://json-ld.github.io/json-ld-star/)